# Decode Alt codes with python

Tags: python, keycode

On machine with windows if u hold alt key and type 1071 on keypad u'll get `/` symbol alt+1069 = `-` and etc

How do i convert those codes to symbols in python 2?

I tried to use `unichr()` but it returns wrong symbols.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code

Comment: desktop version https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code